# Better alternative to Invoke() when changing state of other forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

In my program, I have one form tell another form to change its textbox using:

```
MainForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
    MainForm.textBoxValue = "Hello, World!";
}));
```

Otherwise, I get this error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '[...]' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Is there a better practice when making changes to other forms?

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** create a form on another thread.  Worker threads are to do work, the UI thread is there to display UI.  Never mix them up, the consequences are far worse than what you are trying to deal with now.

Comment: @HansPassant What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search would have helped you, but here is a link that you can read about the problem [Thread-Safe Calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)

A particular piece of code that might be interesting for you is this code example:

```
// This method demonstrates a pattern for making thread-safe  
// calls on a Windows Forms control.   
//  
// If the calling thread is different from the thread that  
// created the TextBox control, this method creates a  
// StringArgReturningVoidDelegate and calls itself asynchronously using the  
// Invoke method.  
//  
// If the calling thread is the same as the thread that created  
// the TextBox control, the Text property is set directly.   

private void SetText(string text)  
{  
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the  
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.  
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.  
    if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)  
    {     
        StringArgReturningVoidDelegate d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(SetText);  
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        this.textBox1.Text = text;  
    }  
}
```

Hope this helps. 
Cheers and happy coding!